# How to prevent 'changed' flag when 'register'-ing a variable?

Tags: ansible

I have a `register` task to test for the installation of a package:

```
tasks:
  - name: test for nginx
    command: dpkg -s nginx-common
    register: nginx_installed
```

Every run it gets reported as a "change":

```
TASK: [test for nginx] ********************************************************
changed: [vm1]
```

I don't regard this as a change... it was installed last run and is still installed this run. Yeah, not a biggy, just one of those untidy OCD type issues.

So am I doing it wrong?  Is there some way to use `register` without it always being regarded as a change?

The [verbose] output is untidy, but the only way I've found to get the correct return code.

`TASK: [test for nginx] ********************************************************
changed: [vm1] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["dpkg", "-s", "nginx-common"], "delta": "0:00:00.010231", "end": "2014-05-30 12:16:40.604405", "rc": 0, "start": "2014-05-30 12:16:40.594174", "stderr": "", "stdout": "Package: nginx-common\nStatus: install ok 
...
\nHomepage: http://nginx.net"}`

Comment: For that specific case, you can also consider using [`package_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_facts_module.html)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It’s described in official documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed).

```
tasks:
  - name: test for nginx
    command: dpkg -s nginx-common
    register: nginx_installed
    changed_when: false
```

Answer (score 13):

It is the `command` module causing the changed state, not the `register` parameter.

You can set [`changed_when:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#overriding-the-changed-result) to something that is only true when something changed (also look at [`failed_when`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure)). If your task don't change anything, you might want to set [`check_mode`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html#enabling-or-disabling-check-mode-for-tasks) as well. (Especially if other steps depend on the value)

This gives:

```
tasks:
  - name: Test for nginx
    command: dpkg -s nginx-common
    register: nginx_installed
    changed_when: false
    failed_when: false  # dpkg -s returns 1 when packages is not found
    check_mode: yes # this can safely run in check_mode
```