# changed_when not working if the result of the task is failed

Tags: ansible

Why am I not able to use `changed_when` to change the state of a task that return `failed` to `changed`?

For example, I have a custom module that allows me to check the existence of a volume, it will failed if the volume doesn't exist.

Playbook snippet:

```yaml
---
- name: Example ansible playbook
  tasks:
    - name: Check existence of the volume
      custom_name_space_my_volume:
        name: ABC #name of the volume
      changed_when: true
```

If the volume `ABC` doesn't exist, the result is `failed`. But why didn't `change_when: true` causes the result to return `changed` instead?

**Note:** The example above might not make logical sense since it's not doing something useful. But I just wanted to use it as a sample for the question I have.

Comment: There are additional discussions you may find interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23946112/320399 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/31731756/320399 , and https://stackoverflow.com/q/62182998/320399

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `failed` overrides `changed`, when a task fails.

For example, take the shell-module. By default it will always show changed, as ansible can't decide if your script did anything or not. But it can also fail, if the script exits with an error-code that is not `0`. When it does that, you want it to show `failed` and not `changed`.

To make sure, your task will never end up `failed`, you can add `failed_when: false`.

```yaml
---
- name: Example ansible playbook
  tasks:
    - name: Check existence of the volume
      custom_name_space_my_volume:
        name: ABC #name of the volume
      changed_when: true
      failed_when: false
```

This will make your task to never show `failed`, so it would be better to provide a sensible expression to mark it as `failed` when it actually failed.